# Call method from managed dll c#

Tags: c#, dll

Using ILSPY i find out that there is `BV method` available inside `bvlsFortran.dll` 
However ILSPY says it is `CALCBV!BV` 
[image]
to see if that is correct I added as reference in Visual Studio and then on main: 
[image]

```
    ![enter image description here][3]

    Assembly SampleAssembly;
    SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("bvlsFortran.dll");
    // Obtain a reference to a method known to exist in assembly.
    MethodInfo Method = SampleAssembly.GetTypes()[0].GetMethod("CALCBV!BV");
    // Obtain a reference to the parameters collection of the MethodInfo instance.
    ParameterInfo[] Params = Method.GetParameters();
    // Display information about method parameters.
    // Param = sParam1
    //   Type = System.String
    //   Position = 0
    //   Optional=False
    foreach (ParameterInfo Param in Params)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Param=" + Param.Name.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("  Type=" + Param.ParameterType.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("  Position=" + Param.Position.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("  Optional=" + Param.IsOptional.ToString());
    }
```

And it is correct it displays info about it.

[image]
How can I call that method?
I can not write `CALCBV!BV` because compiler complains...
If I write `BV` or `bvlsFortran` on method it does not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a .Net based dll, and you any ways are referencing it in your application, why are you using reflection? Try calling the method directly instead through `bvlsFortran.BV`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Invoke` on the `Methodinfo` with an Array of the arguments you want to pass to that function.

The Name `CALCBV!BV` could be an result of obfuscation, the publisher of that dll does not want you to call it directly.

```
Method.Invoke( args );
```